# What is the correct definition of a Cunningham chain of length $n$?

Tags: prime-numbers, definition

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain),

> *A Cunningham chain of the first kind of length n is a sequence of prime numbers $(p_1, \ldots, p_n)$ such that for all $1 ≤ i < n, p_i+1 = 2p_i + 1$.  Hence each term of such a chain except the last is a Sophie Germain prime, and each term except the first is a safe prime.*

But then a **complete Cunningham chain** is defined:

> *A Cunningham chain is called complete if it cannot be further extended, i.e., if the previous and the next terms in the chain are not prime numbers.*

But the first definition already forbids the last prime $p_n$ from being "extended" further. So when one talks about a Cunningham chain of length $n$, does one refer to a chain such that there *might* be another prime extending the 
chain further, or explicitly forbidding the chain from being extended further?

In other words, does a Cunningham chain of length $n$ explicitly forbid the last prime from being a Sophie Germain prime or does it leave this possibility open?

Another way to ask the question would be:

*Does a Cunningham chain of length $n+1$ contain a Cunningham chain of length $n$?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incomplete Cunningham chain is also valid, but of course complete chains are of particular interest.

For example, it is interesting, how long a chain can become upto some given limit.

A natural interpretation should be that a chain that can be lengthened is still a chain, but not complete.

PFGW is a software that can explicitely search for cunningham chains.